Can a defensive player in softball / baseball wear a batter's glove when not at bat?
Softball:   Shortstop was wearing a batter's glove on his throwing hand while playing his position on the field.  Is it legal to do so?  Can't find the answer in a rule nor casebook.

Yes, a defensive player in softball or baseball can wear a batter’s glove while playing defense. There are no specific rules prohibiting this, and some players choose to wear batting gloves for better grip and protection against blisters or abrasions. By that logic, it counts as "defensive protective equipment", which is legal. My source was rule 2.10.
EDIT, I just remembered this: I, in fact, once did this for a brief period at the beginning of my career for largely the same reason, grip and protection from blistering and abrasion, also, it was easier to just take the gloves out into the field rather than take them off and stow them in my bag. However, I stopped this almost as quickly as I started it because it made my hands feel "bulky" and hindered my ability to barehand field a ball and made throwing uncomfortable. This was before I was a pitcher and was instead playing 3rd base, so throwing was a big part of my job. The cons outweighed the pros. Some people, however, may not have this problem and it's just me.
